# Dynamically change PageSize in JTable

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to resize dynamically jQuery JTable in PHP with this code:

```
$t('#TicketTableContainer').jtable('option', 'pageSize', pageSize);
$t('#TicketTableContainer').jtable('reload');
```

Where pageSize it's a value that I calculate dinamically when page was resized. 
For make that I use these functions:

```
$t(window).resize(function() {
    if(this.resizeTO) clearTimeout(this.resizeTO);
this.resizeTO = setTimeout(function() {
    $t(this).trigger('resizeEnd');
}, 500);
});

$t(window).bind('resizeEnd', function() {
//do something, window hasn't changed size in 500ms
    console.log('ResizeEnd');
    pageSize = calculatePageSize();
    $t('#TicketTableContainer').jtable('option', 'pageSize', pageSize);
    $t('#TicketTableContainer').jtable('reload');
});
```

The new pageSize value is calculate only when resize event is ended.
With this code nothing happen and I don't understand how I can obtain the same effect that JTable offer if pageSizeArea option is enabled and all resize function work dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The [pageSize](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference/GeneralOptions#genopt-pageSize) option is for viewing the number of rows in a page not for window resizing behavior.

Comment: Hi, ok I understand this but I don't use pageSize for it I calculate the dimension of the view and, after it, I calculate dinamically the pageSize.